# Rails form without a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-routing

I'm making a super simple app that is essentially just a controller and some views. I can't figure out how to make the form submit and then redirect to the another action.

Here is my code:

```
# app/controllers/wizard_controller.rb

class WizardController < ApplicationController
  def calculate

    # process data from form here

    redirect_to controller: 'wizard', action: 'show'
  end

  def show
    # print processed data here
  end
end
```

This is what the `wizard#calculate` view looks like:

```
<div class="alert alert-info">
    <h2>Get advice on where to live in 3 easy steps!</h2>
</div>

<br/>

<%= form_tag(:controller => "wizard", :action => "calculate") do %>

 ... form fields ...

<%= submit_tag("Submit") %>

<% end %>
```

At this point, just going to `/wizard/calculate` redirects to `/wizard/show` right away since there isn't a conditional statement before the `redirect_to ...` line.

**Edit: Solved using responses on twitter**
I was basically trying to get form data and process it all in the same action. I solved this by splitting `calculate` into `setup`, the view that has the form and `calculate` where I process the data and redirect to `show`.

Also, `<%= form_tag "/wizard/calculate", method: "get" do %>` helped submit the form data accurately.

Thanks for all the responses, it helped a whole lot to get to understanding how this works in rails.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want the user to experience? It sounds like you want them to see the calculate results before sending them to the 'show' page -- is that correct?

Comment: I realize this is off point, but this sounds like an app that would be much more simply built with Sinatra, especially if there is really no model or db needed.

Comment: @KevinBedell , yeah I was trying to do both in the same action sort of. Realized that's not how it works, figured out a solution by splitting that into two actions.

Comment: @SteveRowley I actually don't know anything about Sinatra, but I'll certainly give it a shot sometime.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what your question is. Where you have `#process form data here` you have to well, process the form data.

If you do not have a model you can access the posted values via `params`. For example if you have a field on your form named address you would use `params[:address]` to access the value in your controller.

Comment: how would the `calculate` action know when the form has been submitted though?

Comment: my question is 'how do I link the form submission with the calculate action? and then redirect to the show action?"

Comment: You should see in the server log that when you click the submit button, the browser makes a request to /wizard/calculator. That's happening because your HTML form tag's action is set to "/wizard/calculate" (that's what form_tag generates, view the source on the page to see). Right now #calculate doesn't have anything to do, so it's just jumping right to the redirect. If you give it something to do, such as take the values from the params hash and send them to a database, that will happen before the redirect.

Comment: The problem turned out to be that I was trying to send form data to an action that I was using to display the form in the first place. Took a while to understand that. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your routes aren't set up.

In config/routes.rb

```
match '/wizard/calculate' => 'wizard#calculate'
match '/wizard/show' => 'wizard#show'
```

There are more elegant ways to set up routes, but this should work for your super simple app.

Otherwise, your controller and form are fine.

Comment: I've already got `get "wizard/calculate"` and `get "wizard/show"` in my routes

Comment: Then you have everything you need. What's your question?